# Covering a ductwork bulkhead with pine board

Tags: wood, beam

I would like to make a wood beam with pine board to cover a ductwork bulkhead in the upper corner of the kitchen.

Is it possible to do this or do I have to leave it the way it is?[image]

Comment: Do you mean a duct?

Comment: Also, you're going to need to provide more information. While it doesn't seem like you *can't* do it, adding a picture and some drawings of what you're proposing will help us understand if what you're trying to do is a good idea or not.

Comment: Is that the duct above the archway?  Is it wrapped in sheetrock?  What are the dimensions?

Answer (score 3):

If the goal is to make the duct look like a wood beam it can be done but it depends on how the duct was supported and sheetrock attached. If ribs were installed around the duct and the sheetrock attached to them it will be easy , if the sheetrock was glued to the duct it will take more work but still can be done. The reason I mentioned sheetrock glued to ducts is I have run into this several times and I would not hang anything on it until properly supported.

Comment: Ok thanks for your advice. I will have to look into this before I actually takle it.

Answer (score 0):

You can cover that soffit with w/e you want. But if you pull the soffit down, you'll have nothing to attach your fake beam to.

IMO **it will look fake because it's wider than it is tall**. You could trick me if it only covered the face and if it had a reveal on the bottom. E.g., that's a 10" high soffit; slap a 2x12 on the face of it. Now it's a beam ;)

A 4x12 would look even better, but it'd be too heavy and expensive. That you could fab up out of three pieces of plywood (or one-by stock if it's longer than 8'): 12" front, 4" bottom, and a 2" reveal on the back side.